# How to make a lot of text fit inside html table cell

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a table with cells in Angular/html/css and my cells have to be able to hold a lot of text. My Problem os just that the text will overflow the cell and i need it to just fit inside so it looks nice.

[image]

Here is my angular html code:

```css
.theTable {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 200%;
  border: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

td {}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<div class="theTable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ErrorMessage</th>
        <th>StackTrace</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of ListOfStuff">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.automatedTestName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.errorMessage}}</td>
      <td>{{item.stackTrace}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: You can try this table tr td { word-break: break-all; } it you went a single word break when free space not found... Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to  use `[word-wrap: break-word]` in your `td`

```
td {
  word-wrap: break-word
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have long words without even having a space. Use `word-break:break-all` for your `td` element. It will break the long text words which does not having spaces.

```
.theTable td {
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Also when you write CSS, don't target the element directly like `td` or `tr`. Because that will apply all over the places in your page. Target the element with the specific class or keep one class in the main table and always refer that class for targeting inner element like below.

```
.theTable {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .theTable td,.theTable th {
   max-width: 450px;
   width: 200%;
   border: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 15px;
   font-size: 2vh;
 }

 .theTable td {}

 .theTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
 }
```

You have the wrong table structure like `<tbody>` is missed and applied `font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;` for `div` element instead of `table`. Update your code like below.

```
 .theTable table {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
 }

 <div class="theTable">
   <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ErrorMessage</th>
          <th>StackTrace</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of ListOfStuff">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.automatedTestName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.errorMessage}}</td>
            <td>{{item.stackTrace}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody> 
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are right, but in angular you have many html classes and they all have their own css classes too. There is like a <div> heracy of html classes and i only use this table in this html class, therefore i just target the element diractly. It wont effect other parts of my website in this case.